# Finding Cartesian equation of geometric shapes.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

I am a freshman college student and always trying to figure out an equation of any types of 2D curves or shapes that I see. Now my question is that  are there any general Cartesian equations by which I can express any quadrilaterals or any shape of polygons(including irregular shapes) in 2D? Please explain it details.

Comment: Straight line equation for all connecting pairs of points

Comment: Any polygon can in principle be represented by linear B-splines.

Comment: Please mention some sites or PDFs where I could find about "linear B splines".